# AndroidImageSlider library memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Has anybody solved **daimajia AndroidImageSlider** library memory leak?

I use it in my project and it perfectly fulfills all the needs.
The only trouble is memory leak which occurs after fragment recreation,
so old instances of this "sliding gallery" remain in memory and it leads to OutOfMemory.

I tried overriding onDetachedFromWindow method in SliderLayout.java

```
@Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    if(mCycleTimer != null) mCycleTimer.cancel();
    if(mCycleTask != null) mCycleTask.cancel();
    if(mResumingTask != null) mResumingTask.cancel();
    if(mResumingTimer != null) mResumingTimer.cancel();
    mh.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

as described here: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/issues/122

Also of course I call `removeAllSliders()` and `stopAutoCycle()` in `onStop()` method
But unfortunately it doesn't help

Grateful for any advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case somebody struggles with the same issue,
I finally found the solution:

The key is to use WeakReferences for Sliders.

So how it looks in my case:

```
// I use self modified CustomSliderView, but you are free to use base sliders as well
WeakHashMap<Integer, CustomSliderView> mWaeakSliderMap;
```

then in onCreateView add sliders in this way:

```
mWaeakSliderMap = new WeakHashMap<>();

// adding sliders to the weak map
// sAdvertisementBitmaps is an ArrayList of Files in my case
for (int i = 0; i < sAdvertisementBitmaps.size(); i++) {
    final CustomSliderView sliderView = new CustomSliderView(mContext);
    sliderView.image(sAdvertisementBitmaps.get(i));

    mWaeakSliderMap.put(i, sliderView);
}

// attaching sliders to the slider layout
for (Map.Entry<Integer, CustomSliderView> entry : mWaeakSliderMap.entrySet()) {
    mSliderLayout.addSlider(entry.getValue());
}
```

Also in SliderLayout.java
I made next fields static:
**mCycleTimer; mCycleTask; mResumingTimer; mResumingTask;**

So it prevents useless recreating TimerTask objects.

Now memory leak is almost solved

Comment: Where is the part in your code about clearing memory?

Comment: @XueQing It's been a while ago... It was probably not the very best solution.  But in this sample it was solved with WeakHashMap and using one (static) Timer instead of producing new ones over and over again.

Comment: P.S. For now, I would certainly just not use this library

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you tell me a better library for slding images?

Comment: Today I am sure you don't really need a library for such a simple purpose. Just use a ViewPager + TabLayout for the indicator and perform auto scroll with RxJava's Observable.interval()